# Can you retrieve datapoints if you missed them during the mission?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

According to the [IGN wiki](https://www.ign.com/wikis/horizon-zero-dawn/Hologram), it looks like I missed a hologram datapoint during the Deep Secrets of the Earth mission. The wiki says it is automatically obtained, but somehow I finished that mission without triggering this one:

DATAPOINT 13 - GAIA LOG: 5 JUNE 2065

Can I still retrieve this datapoint after the mission has completed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can return to the Zero Dawn facility at Sunfall after the Deep Secrets of the Earth mission. You can't use the original entrance but an alternative entrance should be shown on your map.

If I remember correctly the three log entry hologram datapoints are in Elisabet's office and, yes, they can be missed.

Comment: Thanks, I went back and got it!  Also found this list:  https://www.reddit.com/r/horizon/comments/5yda2p/compiling_all_datapoints/

Comment: does this also apply to audio datapoint in "into the borderlands", cause I keep scanning it with my focus yet nothing appears in my data progress

Comment: @JonasMorthorstBruun I haven't played this for quite a while (playing Forbidden West instead). Loading an old completed game I can certainly still go to where Aloy and Erend find Ersa. As I approached Dervahl's camp the Recording Device audio was automatically added as a datapoint (although I already had it). I have an idea you might have to interact with the Recording Device rather than just scanning it.

Comment: @JonasMorthorstBruun Also there a couple of other things in that final room that you can only scan - you want the Recording Device near the entrance.